# Always Redirecting to facebook and showing "You have already authorized" page

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

Below are the steps that we are doing and resulting in problem:-

1) Firstly I would like to state that we have  used the facebook connect plugin to work with facebook in our ios app using phonegap.

2)We have an option in the app where we can login through facebook.Our app will fetch all related information from facebook by going to the page "You have already authorized this app". opened in the safari browser.This page also contained one OK and CANCEL button.One screenshot is attached of that screen.

3) Once we press Ok button it will comeback to the app and show the information fetched.If we press cancel button it does not fetch anything.Likewise while in the app we have dashboard page were after facebook login we land.

4)After landing on the dashboard page we have a left panel were we have a tab named "search for friends".

5) We click on the tab and we will be taken to search for friends page.
While in the page if we write name of a person and press search button below,it again takes to the page of facebook opened in the safari browser having the name "You have already authorized the app" with an ok and cancel button.

This feature of constant redirection is causing problems for my user and is making the app clumsy.Help is needed.Please do revert back.

Search implementation of facebook in our app code snippet:-

```
 var searchFB = function ()
            {
                facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
                     function (response)
                     {
                         if (response.status === 'connected') {
                             sstatus = "true";
                             var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                             var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                         }
                         else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

                         } else {

                         }
                 });

                 if (sstatus == "true")
                 {
                      $('#clist').html('');
                      FBid=[];
                      FBname=[];
                      var textVal = document.getElementById('search-basic').value;
                      var searchval=textVal.split(" ").join("+");
                     // accessToken=JSON.stringify(response);
                      revStr = window.localStorage.getItem("token");

                                                   facebookConnectPlugin.api( "search?q="+searchval+"&limit=10&type=user&access_token="+revStr,["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_hometown",
                                                                                                                                                "user_location",

                                                                                                                                                "user_education_history",
                                                                                                                                                "user_work_history",
                                                                                                                                                "user_events",
                                                                                                                                                "user_friends",
                                                                                                                                                "user_about_me",
                                                                                                                                                "user_activities"],
                             function (response)
                             {
                                 if (sstatus == "true")
                                 {
                                 window.localStorage.setItem("token",revStr);
                                 var i=0;
                                 for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
                                 {
                                 FBid.push(response.data[i].id);
                                 FBname.push(response.data[i].name);
                                 //    addresses.push(response.data[i].location);
                                 }
                                 var j=0;

                                 for(j=0;j<FBname.length;j++)
                                 {
                                 $('#clist').append("<li class='clearfix' data-rel='popup' data-position-to = 'window' data-transition ='fade' id ='select_ppl' onclick='callID("+FBid[j]+")'><p>"+ FBname[j]+"</p></li>");
                                 }

                                 }
                             }
                             ,
                             function (response)
                             {
                             //showAlert(JSON.stringify(response));
                             return response;
                             }
                         );
           }

        }
```

Comment: Looks like you are either trying to login the user or ask for the permissions every time you tap on the search button. If the user has already granted this permission then no need to ask for it again.